# WKWebView stop calling Javascript when goes to background

Tags: swift

Tried to attach `WKWebview` to `UIApplication.shared.keywindow` view hierarchy. When the app goes to background, the API keeps running forever. But when open the app again, I got this problem:

> [Error] Failed to load resource: The operation couldn’t be completed.
> Software caused connection abort

```
var gOffscreenView: UIView? = nil

func retainWKWebViewOffscreen(webView: WKWebView) {
    if (gOffscreenView == nil) {
        gOffscreenView = constructOffscreenView()
    }
    gOffscreenView?.addSubview(self.webView)
}

func cleanUpOffscreenView() {
    if (gOffscreenView?.subviews.count == 0) {
        gOffscreenView?.removeFromSuperview()
        gOffscreenView = nil
    }
}

func constructOffscreenView() -> UIView {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    view.clipsToBounds = true
    
    let appWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    appWindow?.addSubview(view)
    
    return view
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if (keyPath == self.kMoPubFrameKeyPathString) {
        self.webView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
    } else {
        self.webView.frame = self.view.frame
    }
}

@objc func keepWebViewRunning(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    self.webView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    self.retainWKWebViewOffscreen(webView: self.webView)
}

@objc func remove(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    self.webView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
}
```

I follow this link https://github.com/mopub/mopub-ios-sdk/blob/master/MoPubSDK/Internal/HTML/MPWebView.m

I also tried setting the timer to call the dummy javascript function to keep wkwebview doesn't go to idle mode but have the same issue.

Comment: Share some code with us.

Comment: Updated the code